# Is it possible to invoke a SQL function like GETDATE() when inserting or updating via Simple.Data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, simple.data

For overall data consistency, I generally I prefer storing the current datetime for new/updated records with the current time on the database server, as it may not be in sync with the invoking server (and if using multiple web servers, they may also be out of sync with each other).

Is it possible to do this via Simple.Data, without having to resort to a stored procedure call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no Simple.Data reference to GETDATE. It's something I plan to address in v2; I will see if the code can be retro-fitted to v1.

Comment: Thanks; I have a local clone and wouldn't mind helping/testing if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Simple.Data

But can you try adding a default to the column:

```
 RecordLastUpdatedOn datetime2(7) Null default(GetDate())
```

You can add it after the column is created by using the alter column/add constraint method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `Simple.Data` but you could let SQL Server handle generating the DateTime.

Just leave the INSERTED column empty and SQL Server will set the default to the current date.

```
CREATE TABLE Table(
    INSERTED DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of defaults, but they only solve the problem for inserts.